# Height is 0 for table view cells that added by registering nib.

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, frame

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` built in a separate xib file, and I added it into my table view dynamically by calling:

`[self.tableview registerNib:theNib forCellReuseIdentifier:theIdentifier];`

I returned the height in `[tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]` like this:

`return ((UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theIdentifier]).frame.size.height;`

The problem is, every time the hight return is 0.

Is there anyway to return the height correctly (should be height of cell in the xib file) except hard code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method is trying to get a cell from the existing ones if any. But because the first time you call this method, no cell was created, it will probably return nil, and the result for height will be 0.

All the other calls of this method will try to use the exiting cell height, but will also be 0 all the times.

Try to do something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
  NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibForCellName owner:self option:nil];

  for (id obj in nib) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
      cell = (UITableViewCell *) obj;
      break; 
    }
  }
}

return cell.frame.size.height;
```